How can I dynamically create a task so that its result is also used in dynamically created tasks?
Please tell me how can I create tasks dynamically so that subsequent tasks are also created dynamically and then these tasks are executed as zip? Sorry if I explained it poorly, I'll try to show it.

If I were making a loop I would do it like this:
_get_unique_brands = get_unique_brands()
_get_brands = get_brands()
for brand in _get_unique_brands:
    brands_batch = get_brands_batch(brands=_get_brands, filter_=_get_unique_brands)
    for brand, group in brands_batch:
        _get_brand_group = get_brand_group(brand, group)
        _transform = transform(_get_brand_group)
        _upload = upload(_transform)

        _get_brand_group >> _transform >> _upload

But unfortunately xcomarg can't be iterated or have data taken from it. How can this problem be solved?
